# Обработка ошибки сети

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Здравсвуйте! Появилась задача при запросах к API при каких либо "Network error" выводить соответствующее сообщение. Вот только Safari (мобильный) например часто делает abort запросов, если например выходишь из браузера, и потом когда человек возвращается в браузер он встречает надоедливое окошко "У вас проблемы с интернетом". Это происходит потому что запросы к API происходят по setInterval. Я принял решение не выводить эту ошибку, если запрос был фоновый по setInterval. Вот только обработка ошибок для всех методов API общая, можно ли как-то через error.config узнать что за запрос был? Проверить по URL запроса конечно можно, но это получится кривовато. 
Чтобы было понятно, о чём я. Используется интерцепторы ответа на запрос:

```
http.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
}, function(error){
console.log(error.config);
if(error.message === 'Network Error')
alert("У вас проблемы с интернетом")
});
```

У меня конечно есть идея использовать отдельный инстанс axios для методов setInterval. Но этот вариант не очень нравится, хотелось бы что-то более элегантное. Например, чтобы создавая axios запрос, можно было передать какой-то параметр в этот error.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока формулировал вопрос, сам догадался. В axios этот config можно передавать с запросом:

```
http.get('api-uri', {test:'1'})
```

И параметр test будет доступен в error.config

Comment: Было бы ещё интересно узнать как сделать чтобы это в typescript работало

Comment: Кстати, это [не будет работать](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1718) в axios 0.19. Вместо этого рекомендуется использовать поле `customConfig` запроса